# How to run a series of checks?

Tags: ruby, comparison

I'm trying to run a series of if/else statements but right now they basically end up being deeply nested if/else statements.

I'm ultimately wanting to say: If A isn't true, run B. If B isn't true, run C. If C isn't true, run D, and so on.

Crude example:

```
if a == b
  return true
else
  c = d/e
  if c = a
    return true
  else
    g = h*i

    if g == true
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need `else` when you're returning from the first branch of an `if`, so your

```
if (condition)
  return true
else
  # otherwise code
end
```

should always be written

```
if (condition)
  return true

# otherwise code
```

This can be written more succinctly in Rails:

```
return true if (condition)

# otherwise code
```

Secondly, this pattern is particularly hideous:

```
if (condition)
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

You should *always* prefer to simply return the condition, which is exactly equivalent (assuming the condition evaluates to boolean true/false):

```
return (condition)
```

Put these together and you get this drastically simplified, un-nested but identical code:

```
return true if a == b

c = d/e

return true if c == a

g = h*i

return g == true
```

Comment: You can also "cast" the condition result to boolean like so: `return !!(condition)`

Answer (score 1):

```
return true if a == b
c = d/e
return true if c == a
g = h*i
return true if g == true
return false
```

You can use statement modifiers in Ruby to add conditional logic. So, instead of nested if statements, you can just do what you plan to do *if* some condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, since you return when success is detected, there is no reason to nest the if statements. The following:

```
return true if a == b
c = d/e
return true if c == a
g = h*i
return g
```

would do exactly the same as your example. (Actually, I don' think my final return statement is required either)